# autocomplete directory name with C

Tags: c, linux, autocomplete

I have a C code, which prompts users for list of directory name, it just uses plain scanf() to receive the input and proceeds. Now I would like to provide autocomplete for directory names (like bash does). Say user enter /home/a and press TAB - it displays list of available user directories that begins with 'a'.how to achieve this?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: You're using `scanf` for user input? Man, you're so far off from getting anything like this to work.

Comment: @ joachim-pileborg, always I used to try something before posting it,my firefox recently closed tab history shows "http://cc.byexamples.com/2008/06/16/gnu-readline-implement-custom-auto-complete/" and http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info /rlman_2.html#SEC36 . Just posted the query assuming someone have a better tutorial or github for this.

Comment: By the way, see the [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library, it has the actual tab-completion part built in. You just have to supply the list of names. See [`opendir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) and [`readdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) for the last part.

Comment: @ melpomene, hihi :) Yes, scanf so far helped this simple code,now looking to improve it a bit.

Comment: Thanks joachim-pileborg,Will check the readline library,seems like that's the only way. I thought,there might be an auto-complete api,which takes file-type as input and list them :) but anyway,I can pass the names to readline with readdir.thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` is not suitable for any kind of auto-complete or even interactive editing beyond the basic level (essentially just backspace) that the kernel cooked-mode terminal driver provides. If you want to do fancier interactive input, you need to change the terminal modes so you get each key event and process them yourself, or you can use a library like `readline` that does this for you.

Comment: Readline is a fantastic library; notice that its license is GPL, not LGPL. So the original poster will have to publish his own code as a free GPL-ed software if he distributes it.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a fantastic library. It has lots of nasty issues like global state and failure to be robust under failure conditions. But it is popular and easy to use. I believe there are non-copyleft alternatives that do roughly the same thing if license is an issue, but I'm not sure how they compare in other regards.